# how to get numbers after the semicolon using regex

Tags: python

```
line=[::1]:12345
```

How do I extract `::1` and `12345` separately using regex in python?

Comment: Colon or semicolon? And what have you tried?

Comment: post more data, does this is the only line you want to process?

Answer (score 1):

```
line='[::1]:12345'

import re
match = re.findall(r'::\d+|(?<=:)\d{2,}', line)
print(match)
```

out:

```
['::1', '12345']
```

Comment: @K48 Really? How is this a link only answer?

Comment: someone left a comment from review (now deleted) voting to delete you answer because it was a link only answer. I just pointed out that this was wrong, your answer is fine and there is no link.